# Does .mouseover and .mouseout still function on a disabled button?

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have spent a long time making this website and I am panicking.

For months if not years my syntax was working fine.

Everything works like a domino effect. Mostly every button is disabled. You click a button, and like a rabbit hole, specific buttons enable and disable with every subsequent click.

Now when I open the site. It's like the code just shat itself and isn't reading anything properly. I move the mouse around and everything that's embedded in a mouseover event is working when it's not supposed to.

Section of my code:

```js
var art2 = document.getElementById('drawing2');
var art3 = document.getElementById('drawing3');
var art4 = document.getElementById('drawing4');
var arttext = document.getElementById('drawingtext');
var arttext2 = document.getElementById('drawingtext2');

playface.addEventListener('mouseover', playface);
stopface.addEventListener('mouseout', stopface);

function playface() {
  art3.classList.add('intervention');
  setTimeout(() => {
    art3.classList.remove('intervention');
  }, 650);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art3.classList.add('creep');
  }, 651);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art3.classList.remove('creep');
  }, 1020);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art2.classList.add('bleed4me');
  }, 806);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art2.classList.remove('bleed4me');
  }, 950);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art2.classList.add('bleed4me');
  }, 990);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art2.classList.remove('bleed4me');
  }, 2030);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art2.classList.add('sonk');
  }, 15050);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art3.classList.add('blick');
  }, 17105);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art3.classList.remove('blick');
  }, 20302);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art4.classList.add('blick2');
  }, 17175);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art4.classList.remove('blick2');
  }, 18225);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art2.classList.remove('sonk');
  }, 17755);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art2.classList.add('orgfe');
  }, 17775);
  setTimeout(() => {
    arttext.classList.add('hertbrek');
  }, 17775);
  setTimeout(() => {
    arttext2.classList.add('anner');
  }, 17775);
  setTimeout(() => {
    art2.classList.remove('orgfe');
  }, 19805);
  setTimeout(() => {
    arttext.classList.remove('hertbrek');
  }, 19805);
  setTimeout(() => {
    arttext2.classList.remove('anner');
  }, 19805);
}

function stopface() {
  art3.classList.remove('intervention');
  art3.classList.remove('creep');
  art2.classList.remove('bleed4me');
  art2.classList.remove('bleed4me');
  art3.classList.remove('blick');
  art4.classList.remove('blick2');
  art2.classList.remove('sonk');
  art2.classList.remove('orgfe');
  arttext.classList.remove('hertbrek');
  arttext2.classList.remove('anner');
}
```

```html
<div class="facecorn1">
  <h1></h1>
  <div id="facebutt1" class="facebutt1"></div>
  <button id="fbutn1" class='fbutn1' disabled="disabled" style="width: 85px;
                            height: 105px;
                            position: fixed;
                            bottom: 135px;
                            left: 615px;
                            opacity: 0%;" onmouseover="playface()" onmouseout="stopface()">
                </button>


</div>
```

What happens here which is a common setup I'm using. Mouse enters a button and plays something but leaving the button stops it all in a nice clunky way I like.

You'll notice the button is disabled. Clicking another button prior to landing on this page enables the button. But when I first open the website this and every other function like it acts like the button isn't disabled. IT WAS WORKING FINE FOR MONTHS.

I open the error terminal. There's Type Errors everywhere with my addevent listeners. Never had this issue but Fair. So, I did fix that BUT ITS STILL MESSING UP AND IGNORING THE DISABLED ATTRIBUTE, PROPERTY???

If anyone doubts my type error fix I simply changed it to:

```
*buttonid*.addEventListener('*mouseover/out*', (*eventname*);
```

since there's 2 functions, I tried using the same event name still bugging. Then I used a different name for each simply adding a or b at the end respectively and it still was not working.

I fixed all the type errors, but the problem persisted. I don't know if this is a bug. I just can't comprehend how it worked for months, I'm talking since i started working on this in 2021 and suddenly ploop sorry buddy all your code is stupid omg. I WAS USING TUTORIALS EVEN LIKE AGH!!!

Comment: `playface.addEventListener()` is not valid. `playface` is a function, not a DOM element.

Comment: You shouldn't use both `addEventListener()` and `onmouseover/onmouseout`

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? I suspect there's an error that's preventing the JS that enables and disables the button from running.

Comment: @barmar I changed playface to the button id according to the java wiki. It solved the Type Error but the disabled button was still activating the mouseover/out event.

Comment: If you use `addEventListener()`, remove the `onXXX` attributes. One or the other, not both. I don't know if this is related to your problem, but it's just plain wrong.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar how do I listen to the event any other way? I have only Type Errors in the console but after I fixed them there were no errors but the onmouseover/out event was still firing on the disabled buttons.

Comment: `addEventListener()` and `onmouseover` both listen to the event. So you're running your function twice every time the event happens.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that disable attribute does not prevent any events from firing

Comment: I can confirm. See https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/1pao73hj/

Comment: The only events it prevents are click-related. https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/1pao73hj/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, mouseover and mouseout events still fire on disabled buttons. Click, mousedown, and mouseup do not.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".foo").forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    console.log(this.id, "mouseover");
  });
  button.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    console.log(this.id, "mouseout");
  });
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.id, "click");
  });
  button.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    console.log(this.id, "mousedown");
  });
  button.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    console.log(this.id, "mouseup");
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="foo" id="disabled" disabled>
Disabled
</button>
<br>
<button class="foo" id="enabled">
Enabled
</button>
```

The [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-disabled) explains what the `disabled` attribute does:

> A form control that is disabled must prevent any [click](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-click) events that are queued on the user interaction task source from being dispatched on the element.

Informally, click events are those that occur when you press and release the mouse button. Mouse motion events are not click events.

Comment: i'm so confused so it working on my end for years was a bug.....So much of this site was built on a bug ugHHHG... is there a workaround do you know?

Comment: Your `playface()` function could do `if (this.disabled) { return; }` so it ignores disabled elements.